# How to run tests in order of their appearance in test script using nose?

Tags: nose, pytest, nosetests, python-unittest, python-nose

I want run my tests in order of they are written not in alphabetical order that `unittest` does by default.

```
import unittest

class test2(unittest.TestCase):

   def test1(self):
      pass

   def test0(self):
      pass

class test1(unittest.TestCase):

   def testB(self):
      pass

   def testA(self):
      pass
```

In this example I want to set `unittest` or `nosetests` to run tests in order of test1, test0, testB and testA. When I run tests using command line with    `python -m unittest -v mytestmodule`
OR
`nosetests mytestmodule`.

What command line argument should I use in order to do so?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: There are some of the tests that need to run in order otherwise they will not make sense like Registration and Login, I want to Register first and then Login with the newly registered credential. @Alik

Comment: It is a bad practice when one test depends on another.

Comment: I know that, it does not happen on all of my tests. This is Regression test and I need it to be fast. Also, there is no harm in knowing how to change the order of tests. @Alik

Comment: @dbliss I already know about good and bad practices of writing tests, my question is something else and I need to know the answer to it.

Comment: Classes are glorified hash tables.  Ordinarily, they don't have an order.  Now, you can fake it using the [`__prepare__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace) hook, but that's an awful lot of work to support something which isn't a best practice to begin with... so AFAIK unittest and friends don't actually do said work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it using PyTest ordering plugin provided [here.](http://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.org/en/develop/)

I ran tests using `py.test MyTestModule.py -vv` and the results were as follows and test were run in the order of their appearance:

```
MyTestModule.py::test2::test1 PASSED
MyTestModule.py::test2::test0 PASSED
MyTestModule.py::test1::testB PASSED
MyTestModule.py::test1::testA FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command-line argument.  You have a couple of options:

1) Rename your tests.  In your example, all you'd have to do is switch the names for `test1` and `test0`.  This suggestion has been made [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18627017/2623899).

2) Use the plug-in at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002707/a-nose-plugin-to-specify-the-order-of-unit-test-execution).