# Testing Twilio app with multiple requests and different scenarios

Tags: python, heroku, twilio

I've created a Python Twilio app which interacts with a caller through many different URLs. It's made to be stateless and deployed on a load balanced system with a database backend to keep up with stateful call data.

My problem is testing. As I was developing, I was using the Firefox add-on [HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/) to make requests as I went. That worked fine until I made a change in an earlier controller and had to run all the the requests again. It also made it nearly impossible to test scenarios (pressing 1 instead of 2).

I've played with UnitTest a bit, but no luck since there's no guarantee of the order the tests are ran and it's really against the point to have the tests rely on one another.

How do you normally test your Twilio apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logan, hi! Megan from Twilio here.

I'm not sure what framework you're working with but, [Unit Testing Your Twilio App Using Python's Flask and Nose](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/03/unit-testing-your-twilio-app-using-pythons-flask-and-nose.html) is detailed tutorial using the nose test runner to test against Twilio webhook endpoints.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Megan! I really appreciate it! That post is actually where I started my quest. I can't really figure out how how to structure the tests to run sequentially or to have any type of order for the different scenarios. Some scenarios will just be a different key press and some will put back an error. :(

Comment: Hey Logan, try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002707/a-nose-plugin-to-specify-the-order-of-unit-test-execution

Comment: This looks great!! I'll give it a try first thing in the morning